# How to adapt upload_dir to save files outside of WP uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a CPT which is used to manage various assets including image, pdf, CAD and other files.

Our client would like to keep these asset files seperate from their other media files and does NOT want them to appear in the WP media panel.

We have found this useful snippet which allows us to upload to a custom folder inside the WP uploads folder:

```
function my_upload_dir($upload) {
    $upload['subdir']   = '/assets';
    $upload['path']     = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['url']      = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];
    return $upload;
}

add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['xxxx'], $upload_overrides);
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
```

How could we adapt this properly to upload images for this CPT to a custom 'assets' folder, for example: wp-content/assets ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In your wp-config.php file add `define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/assets');`

Comment: @Simon. Thanks but I only want to upload files from the custom post type 'assets' to the wp-content/assets folder! All other files should upload to the default wp-content/uploads folder.

Comment: Ahh apologies for not reading your question properly... I would suggest you need to look into WordPress hooks and find one called before an image is uploaded, and at that point check the post type (try looking at the global post object) let the file be saved and find a hook after to then remove the filter. Hope this makes some sense, might try a proper answer if I get time.